# Python excel to pdf doesn't print all sheets

Tags: python

Any idea why only the first sheet is printed and not 1 and 5?
I tried printing only 5th sheet and that also worked.
I want to print multiple sheets in to pdf.

def excelToPDF(templateFileName, sheetname, outputFileName):

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False

wb_path = templateFileName

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
excel.Visible = False
ws_index_list = [1,5] #1,2,3 also can be used.

wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, outputFileName)
wb.Close(False)
excel.Quit()
excel = None #Release object/resources
wb = None #Release object/resources

return outputFileName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives me a PDF with the contents of sheet 1 and sheet 3. See [Worksheets.Select method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.select).

```py
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False

wb_path = r"foo.xlsx"
outputFileName = r"foo.pdf"

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
excel.Visible = False


wb.WorkSheets(1).Select(True)   # True to replace the current selection with the specified object.
wb.WorkSheets(3).Select(False)  # False to extend the current selection to include any previously selected objects and the specified object.


wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, outputFileName)
wb.Close(False)
excel.Quit()
excel = None #Release object/resources
wb = None #Release object/resources
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. 
I had to use 
wb.WorkSheets(1).Select(True)   # True to replace the current selection with the specified object.
wb.WorkSheets(3).Select(False)